# How to unlink the site name?

Tags: blocks, 10

Core with Olivero theme.

The site name is a link and I want to unlink it.

I want to do it because I already link to the homepage from the main menu and don't want two links to the homepage from the same place (`header`) and I also don't want to waste even one link-crawl of a given crawling budget.

How to unlink a site name?

Comment: Explaining the downvote would be helpful...

Comment: I did not downvote the question but it could be because it has irrelevant and, I think, confusing information as to the reason for the question. It would be enough to say "a project requires the site name not to be hyperlinked".

Comment: @cilefen much thanks. I have edited the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `block--system-branding-block.html.twig` theme file. Most core themes have something like this in it:

```
{% if site_name %}
    <a href="{{ path('<front>') }}" rel="home">{{ site_name }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

In your override template, remove the `<a>` tag.

Comment: I have created such a file and putted that code in it without the `<a>` tags. That breaks down the CSS. I can re-CSS but is there a way to just unlink it without breaking the CSS?

Comment: Link to `#` instead of to `{{ path('<front>') }}`.

Comment: The CSS still appears broken and the link exists but leads nowhere.

Comment: "Link exists and goes nowhere" is what `#` does in HTML. Getting into more detail on that is outside the scope of Drupal Answers. You'll have to update the CSS of course. I don't know what theme you are using nor what is "broken" about the CSS.  Technically I've answered the question. Removing the `<a>` tags removes the link.

Comment: I agree with all you said about HTML. I use Olivero theme (updated the question).